# ~./bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos

I messed up my bash I think. I was trying to change the php path to XAMPP path and somehow I ended up trashing the ~./bash file.

I get the following error now when accessing bash_profile

> -bash: ~./bash_profile: No such file or directory

However if I run `vim ~./bash_profile`
I get the following:

> > E325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name "/var/tmp/bash_profile.swp"
> >               owned by: hsnsd   dated: Fri Mar 23 16:20:43 2018
> >              file name: ~hsnsd./bash_profile
> >               modified: YES
> >              user name: hsnsd   host name: Hassans-MacBook-Pro.local
> >             process ID: 770 While opening file "~./bash_profile"
>
> (1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the
>   case,
>       be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
>       file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution. (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
>       If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r ~./bash_profile"
>       to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
>       If you did this already, delete the swap file "/var/tmp/bash_profile.swp"
>       to avoid this message.
>
> Swap file "/var/tmp/bash_profile.swp" already exists! [O]pen
>   Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:

If I chose Edit anyway and then try running something, I cant save changes since I get E212: Can't open file for writing

I am very new to MAC/Unix and I have no idea what to do.
Is there a way to reset the bash or something?

Comment: `~./bash_profile` ---> `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @liliscent -bash: /Users/username/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Typo, probably the filename is `.bash_profile` in your Home directory ~